# Programming/Hacking

Tags: security, penetration-testing

Lets say I knew an ethical hacker that I wanted to hire to do a penetration test, but trust was an issue. Could I duplicate my system but have its sensitive data removed, and have it untraceable to the company that owns it?

If just the structure and security measures remained, could this duplicate be hacked to see if certain areas can be accessed? I'm guessing it could be done similarly to the 'missions' on hackthissite.org. I could then be informed of the exploits. What would the test site look like?

Could it actually be completely untraceable to its company? How hard would this be?

Comment: "ethical hacker [...] but trust [is] an issue" — Hello contradiction!

Comment: @coreywad: The bad guys are going to tell you that they are ethical as well.

Comment: Could we please continue to make a distinction between *Hacker* and *Cracker*?

Comment: @oosterwal: As much as it annoys me, we lost that battle in the last millenium.  Accept it.

Comment: @btilly: I refuse to give in!

Comment: @oosterwal: I sympathize, but I gave up on correcting people long ago.

Comment: @oosterwal I hate this too, but it's a lost cause.

Answer (score 1):

You generally cannot go around distributing the code for your employers sites.

With their permission, though, what you could do is setup a staging environment (most development environments should have these anyway) and in that sense you can point relevant people to that site (with no real data) for the purposes of providing a penetration test. Of course, it may limit the scope of the validity of their attacks, but not generally so, because you're already basically saying "attack this web infrastructure", and the data they see is kind of irrelevant (as long as it has the same structure); that is the aim of exposing weaknesses in the sites function is independent of data.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the data is entirely irrelevant.  One form of attack is social engineering, and that is harder to do when there are no employees to socially engineer.

Comment: @btilly: Yes, clearly, as I indicated there are some things the main website would be used for, but it should not be offensively attacked from an input point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You could do that, but there are nuances. Just make sure that the structure is not changed. That is, remove non behavioral procedures and create a clone and allow him to test that only.

Bear in mind, though, that even if you remove the sensible data, you can still be hacked. A security flaw can be such that does not rely on behavior, but services and such (which is most times the case).

The tester can easily not report a vulnerability and leave this open as a backdoor to your real application.

Comment: The idea of having the system untraceable to its parent company means that there wouldn't be any issues with rogue hackers. How hard would you say it would be for a medium sized company to make a test duplicate?

Comment: it certainly depends on how the original system is created, but overall it's pretty easy to create a duplicate for virtually any standard system.

Comment: That's nice to hear. Do you think it would still be easy for something as large as chase online banking?

Comment: much more elaborate for sure :) Banking needs all sorts of things, from integrity and authentication testing to even checking what seems to be the smallest detail.